# Why is my Log in System not working?

Tags: php, mysql, password-hash

I've created a system which allows a admin to register another admin with an email address and password to log into a protected area. A admin is registered through this form:

```
<form action="adduser.php" method="POST">
            <label for="emailaddress">Email Address: </label><input type="text" name="emailaddress" />
            <label for="password">Password: </label><input type="password" name="password" />
            <label for="name">Name: </label><input type="text" name="name"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

The adduser.php looks like this:

```
<?php
    require'databaselogin.php';
    if(isset($_POST['emailaddress'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['name'])){
        $result= $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO users (emailaddress, password, name )
                            VALUES(:emailaddress, :password, :name)');
        $hash = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);  
        unset($_POST['submit']);
        $_POST['password'] = $hash;
        $result->execute($_POST);
        header("Location:admin.php");
    }
?>
```

Up to here appears to work the table called users then gets populated with data. I guess potentially it could be using $hash incorrectly than the password stored in the table isn't what the user entered in the password field?

When the user attempts to log in using this form:

```
<form action="login.php" method="POST" >
                <label for="emailaddress">Email Address:</label><input type="text" name="emailaddress"/>
                <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Go" name="submit"/>
            </form>
```

Linking to this php:

```
<?php
    session_start();

        require'databaselogin.php';
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE emailaddress = :emailaddress');
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $criteria = [
            'emailaddress' => $_POST['emailaddress'],
            ];
            $stmt->execute($criteria);

            $user = $stmt->fetch();
            var_dump($user);
            if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password'])) {
                $_SESSION['loggedin'] = $user['id'];
                header("Location:admin.php");
            }
            else {
                header("Location:index.php");
            }
            }
?>
```

With the correct email and password entered into the registration from the website just reloads on index.php rather than taking them to admin.php. I really can't understand the issue here as the code looks sound too me I'm guessing it's an issue with whatever $hash is actually saving to the password field.

If someone can help with this it'd be really appreciated!

Comment: How about this, register a user with a simple password like 1234 and check your table for the stored hash. Then echo a hashed 1234 using the same method, look if the strings match. If they do, the issue has nothing to do with the hash.

Comment: and, what is the password column's length? If it's too short, it's failing for you *silently*.

Comment: What is the result of `var_dump ($user)`?

Comment: and we're all waiting here ever so patiently...

Comment: Turns out it was the password column length,it works now thanks!

Comment: Hah... I knew it hehe and you're welcome Ollie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're not responding to comments, I am submitting the following.

I suspect that your password column's length is too short.

If that is the case, you need to set it at 60+. So, ALTER your column, clear your password rows that contain hashes, create a new hash and try again.

The manual on this:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

> PASSWORD_DEFAULT - Use the bcrypt algorithm (default as of PHP 5.5.0). Note that this constant is designed to change over time as new and stronger algorithms are added to PHP. For that reason, the length of the result from using this identifier can change over time. Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice).

- MySQL *will fail silently* if it is too short. I have seen that happen many times before.

On an added note:

It's best to use `exit;` after each header, otherwise your code may want to continue to execute.

```
if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password'])) {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = $user['id'];
    header("Location:admin.php");
    exit;
}
else {
    header("Location:index.php");
    exit;
}
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Ollie Atkins please check what he said. he is correct